# Apple GameCenter: how to check if playerId is valid (and online) from game server

Tags: iphone, validation

I post some data from my app to my game-server.
This data always contains playedId from GKLocalPlayer.

How my game-server can check if this playerId is valid (online)? (for example by some get/post request to GameCenter server).

Answer (score 0):

For now GameCenter does not support any get/post requests.